# gsutil du with asterisk

Tags: pattern-matching, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

How to get `gsutil` to display directory sizes with asterisk? E.g. when I type `gsutil du [-s] gs://bucket/dirA/*` I would expect to see a size of each "subdirectory".

Alas, `gsutil` only gives either sizes for all underneath "files" (*without -s*), or a single summary size.

Any ideas if this is at all possible with `gsutil`?

ps. I'm aware that 'directory' and 'file' have somewhat different meaning in KV storage such as GCS, but the above functionality is supported in e.g. `hadoop fs -dus s3n://bucker/dirA/*`

Comment: I believe this is a bug. I've filed [#235](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/235)